# php call_user_func_array doesn't work

Tags: php

first time trying to deal with this call_user_func_array, but something isn't working, since I get no response from the function, what can I be missing?

```
function _a_($id, $text) {          
    if($id == 'a') {
    _b_();
    if(substr($text, 0, 8) == "{source}") {
        $campos = substr_replace($text, '', 0, 8);
        $campos = substr($campos, 0, -9);
        $funcao = explode(";", $campos);
        print_r($funcao);
        call_user_func_array($funcao[0], $funcao[1]);
    }
    } else {
        echo $text."<br>";
    }
}
function _b_() {
    echo "b was fired<br>";
}
function _c_($some_text) {
    echo "received a call<br>";
    echo "inside function c: ".$some_text."<br>";
}
_a_("a", "{source}_c_;ola{/source}");
```

Comment: Enable your diagnostics, you get a big fat error message telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Can you post the result of `print_r($funcao);` ?

Comment: Array ( [0] => _c_ [1] => ola )   It now works with the call_user_func_array($funcao[0], array($funcao[1]));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
call_user_func_array($funcao[0], $funcao[1]);
```

=>

```
call_user_func_array($funcao[0], array($funcao[1]));
```

Answer (score 4):

Say either this:

```
call_user_func($funcao[0], $funcao[1]);
```

Or this:

```
call_user_func_array($funcao[0], array($funcao[1]));
```

The latter form is only useful if you need to pass the arguments by reference; see [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) for details.

Answer (score 3):

**call_user_func_array()** expects the second parameter to be an array. Use **call_user_func** if you know the number of parameters.

Comment: can't do, I want this to be dynamic

Comment: Then use ``call_user_func_array()``.